# Getting count and grouping by date range in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to get the count of rows and group them by hour, day or month.

For instance, assume I have the messages

```
_source{
"timestamp":"2013-10-01T12:30:25.421Z",
"amount":200
}
_source{
"timestamp":"2013-10-01T12:35:25.421Z",
"amount":300
}
_source{
"timestamp":"2013-10-02T13:53:25.421Z",
"amount":100
}
_source{
"timestamp":"2013-10-03T15:53:25.421Z",
"amount":400
}
```

Is there a way to get something alone the lines of {date, sum} (not necessarily in this format, just wondering if there is any way i can achieve this)

```
{
{"2013-10-01T12:00:00.000Z", 500},
{"2013-10-02T13:00:00.000Z", 100},
{"2013-10-03T15:00:00.000Z", 400}
}
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Have a look at the [date histogram facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-date-histogram-facet.html)

Comment: I am looking into it now.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 9):

Try with aggregations.

```
{     
  "aggs": {
    "amount_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "week"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "amount"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In addition, if you wanna count number of indexes replace sum content by:

```
"sum": {
  "script": "1"
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: If you just want the number of indices you can leave out the entire second aggregate. You can also add `"min_doc_count": 0` to the `date_histogram` so that every interval is shown leaving gaps if no data is available.

Answer (score 0):

I need Query to fetch data from ElasticeSearch for count of month wise and count of Year wise registered Customer in our platform.
Below Queries are perfectly working and giving data correctly:

here : CustOnboardedOn : is Feild when Cust

Method type: POST

URL: http://SomeIP:9200/customer/_search?size=0

ES Query for Month wise aggregated customer

```
{     
  "aggs": {
    "amount_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "CustOnboardedOn",
        "interval": "month"
      }   
  }
}
}
```

ES Query: Year wise Aggregation.

```
{     
  "aggs": {
    "amount_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "CustOnboardedOn",
        "interval": "year"
      }   
  }
}
}
```